# AllJoyn iOS sample project build failed

Tags: ios, alljoyn

I tried to build the sample project  "AllJoyn iOS project Template" from the [AllSeenAlliance Run Page](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx).

I followed the step by step tuto, and I'm in the step where I need to build all the projects.
After a lot of struggle setting the library searsh path and all for the first project ("AllJoyn iOS project Template"), I am facing an architecture issue at build time :

[ScreenShot of xcode build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfZPd.png)

I am using xcode 7.3.1.

Anyone had the same issue ? Thanks

Ps : More generally, I just need to use the onboarding AllJoyn SDK in a iOS project, so maybe I am trying to build all those projects for nothing and there is a simpler way. If one of you guys already did it, I'm all ears :).

Comment: hello max were you able to run the onboarding samples of alljoyn , if so please also let me know how did you do it. thanks.

Comment: Hello @MoeezAkram . I had to put that issue for later because it was "un-prioritized" (I don't know if it's the word in english). Anyway, I'll be back on that issue from scratch in jannuary probably. If in your side you found something, please let me know as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try building for device, rather than for simulator. For some reason Alljoyn SDK does not contain x64 simulator symbols. If you want to use Simulator, try selecting iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

Dont rely on any solution, Let me tell you clearly, if you are already running the alljoyn sdk than just add the sample files in you previous code, it will definitely work. I am working on alljoyn from last 1 year so you can ask any thing.